# The probability of a vector in the random linear code?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory

For a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, a random linear code of rate $R$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is defined as the kernel of a uniformly random matrix $H\in \mathbb{F}_q^{(1-R)n\times n}$. (Here we assume that $0< R< 1$ and $Rn$ is an integer.)

One claims that for linearly independent vectors $v_1,...,v_k\in \mathbb{F}_q^{n}$,
$$\mathbb{P}(v_1,...,v_k\in C)=\prod_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}(v_i\in C)= q^{-(1-R)kn},$$
where $C$ is a random linear code of rate $R$.

I am wondering how to prove this claim?

I am trying to show that for a non-zero vector $\mathbb{P}(v\in C)=q^{-(1-R)n}$. And for linearly independent vectors, the events that each of them is in $C$ is independent. But I am not sure how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate $H$, we can independently choose each row $w_i$ in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ uniformly at random. Note $v\in Ker(H)$ if $w_i\cdot v=0$ for each $i$. And the subspace $span(v)^{\perp}$ that perpendicular to $v$ has dimension $n-1$, so that $|span(v)^\perp|=q^{n-1}$. And then $$\mathbb{P}(w_i\in span(v)^{\perp})=q^{n-1}/q^n=q^{-1}.$$
Therefore $\mathbb{P}(w_1,...,w_{(1-R)n}\in span(v)^\perp)=q^{-(1-R)n}$.

When we have linearly independent $v_1,..,v_k$, we have
$$dim(span(v_1,...,v_k)^\perp)=n-k$$ and the same argument goes on.